# Inconsistent band structure of bilayer graphene

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, electronic-structure, k-points

## Context

I am performing band structure calculations for bilayer graphene using QE codes. I used `X-crysden` for the k-point mesh `3x3x1` with `50` points along each `k-path (gG-K-M-gG)`. My graphene sheet (`148C`) isn't a traditional cell. I used a `2x2x1` supercell. In the band structure I uploaded, Fermi energy is adjusted to `0ev`. My workflow is as follows-

First I performed a relaxed calculation of the cell with 148C atoms with AA stacking of both layers having a separation of 1 Ang. Then, I performed the band calculation with an appropriate high symmetry path, after which I plotted the bands. @AbdulMuhaymin

```
enter code here
```

Please guide me with the error.

[image]

## Question

The bands do not meet at the k-point but at some other high symmetry point. Also if we zoom in a little there is a band gap that is clearly inconsistent.  Why do we observe such behavior?

Comment: Please, provide the input files as a code block in your question (scf.in, optional nscf.in, bands.in) and your workflow. What structure of bilayer graphene have you used? AA stacking or AB stacking?

Comment: @Akash please add those details as an edit to your question and not in comments

Comment: How can i add files ? @VandanRevanur

Comment: @AkashSaxena you can use three ``` symbol to start and end a code block. You don't need to upload a file. You can copy paste the content of the file into that code block. See https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/6055